# How to extract characters from images where their positions are known?

Tags: image, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have a set of png images of 300dpi . Each image is full of text (not handwritten), digits (not handwritten).

l want to extract each character and save it in a different image.
For each character in the image l have its position stored in csv file.

For instance in image1.png for a given character “k” l have its position :

```
 “k”=[left=656, right=736,top=144,down= 286]
```

Is there any python library which allows to do that ?. As input l have the images (png format) and csv file that contains the position of each character of each images.
after executing the code l stack at this line :

```
img_charac=img[int(coords[2]):int(coords[3]),int(coords[0]):int(coords[1])]
```

l got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: can you show an input image ?

Comment: it's an invoice. https://www.google.fr/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLk6fh4uzSAhWIaxQKHZKeBfwQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.workingpoint.com%2Ffeatures%2Finvoicing&psig=AFQjCNG6GebkPqzUAKDZ9xl4-vvEm5RoBQ&ust=1490363482888717

Comment: @soltitus Do you understand the format and the content of the image ?

Comment: so from this image, you have a csv file with positions of every character (for example, "I" in invoice), is that it ? What is left to do apart from looping over every charcater in the csv file and cropping your image and saving each crop ?

Comment: yes for example in my csv : "l" = [left=32,right=98,top=117, down=280]. Yes my question is about that : how crop the image and save each crop

Comment: OK, I'll post an answer in a few minutes tell me if it's OK for you. Left, right, top and down are the values of the bounding box of each character ? (meaning the highest pixel of the character has a y value of "top", the one on the left has an x value of "left")

Comment: the image is in 300dpi which means (width=2480 ,height=3508) And a given character such as "l" = [left=32,right=98,top=117, down=280] which are the pixels.  Definitely it's the bounding box of each character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understood correctly, this has nothing to do with image processing, just file opening, image cropping and saving.
With a csv file looking like [image: this],
an input image looking like
[image: this]

I get results like [image: this]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import csv

path_csv= #path to your csv

#stock coordinates of characters from your csv in numpy array
npa=np.genfromtxt(path_csv+"cs.csv", delimiter=',',skip_header=1,usecols=(1,2,3,4))
nb_charac=len(npa[:, 0]) #number of characters

#stock the actual letters of your csv in an array
characs=[]
cpt=0
#take characters
f = open(path_csv+"cs.csv", 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    if cpt>=1: #skip header
        characs.append(str(row[0]))
    cpt+=1

#open your image
path_image= #path to your image
img=cv2.imread(path_image+"yourimagename.png")
path_save= #path you want to save to

#for every line on your csv,
for i in range(nb_charac):
    #get coordinates
    coords=npa[i,:]
    charac=characs[i]

    #actual cropping of the image (easy with numpy)
    img_charac=img[int(coords[2]):int(coords[3]),int(coords[0]):int(coords[1])]
    #saving the image
    cv2.imwrite(path_save+"carac"+str(i)+"_"+str(charac)+".png",img_charac)
```

This is sort of quick and dirty, the csv opening is a bit messy for example (you could get all the info with one opening and converting), and should be adapted to your csv file anyway.

Comment: Thankk you a lot @Soltius

Comment: What do you mean by path_stats ? i it path_csv?

Comment: 'img[top:bottom, left:right] ' isn't it ? in my case it doesn't make any cropping

Comment: that's indeed it. Print your top, bottom, left and right values to see if something's wrong.

Comment: My original image has a shape of '(3504,2458,3)' and when l try to crop for instance 'img_charac=img[347:239,275:147]' it gives back no error then l printed the following 'img_charac.shape'  (0,0,3) . what's wrong

Comment: you inverted left and right, also top and bottom. Try img[239:347, 147:275]